# Printing register or variable in decimal form in Intel 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm working on a program for Intel 8086 and though the whole logic seems to be working pretty well, I have a problem with outputting the final result to the user. Namely, I store it in one of the registers but would like to print it out in decimal form, without interpreting it as ASCII characters or other things. I know it's assembly so most probably it won't be as easy as I'd like it to be, but still, what's the easiest way to do it since the regular MOV with 02h doesn't work?

Comment: You have to convert your binary value in the register to a series of ASCII characters, and print those characters.

Comment: Unless your output device can perform the conversion from binary to decimal, you will have to carry it out yourself, and output devices, like the text screen renders ASCII characters. And... what does that "regular MOV with 02h" mean?

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix: I'm guessing the OP meant `INT 21H / AH=02H`.